# Move focus and not selection on keydown for wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am using WPF Datagrid and have overridden OnSelectionChange to support multiple selection from UI as well as from code.

Right now if i press down arrow key on any selected item, selection and focus both moves to next row. I want only focus to move and not selection. I want to select the focused item when space key or escape key is pressed not on up/down arrow key. How to get this behavior. Here is my code -

```
 <Controls:DMDataGrid  Grid.Row="2" x:Name="dgrObjects" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfObjects, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" GridLinesVisibility="None"
                                     CanUserAddRows="false" Background="White"
                                     IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                                     DMItemsList="{Binding SelectedObjects, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                     SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                                     CanUserSortColumns="True" Focusable="True">
            <Controls:DMDataGrid.Resources>
               <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                  <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsObjectSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
               </Style>
            </Controls:DMDataGrid.Resources>
```

Here is code for Selection change behavior-

```
 public class DMDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
      public DMDataGrid()
      {
         SelectionChanged += DMDataGrid_SelectionChanged;
      }

      void DMDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         if (e.AddedItems != null)
         {
            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
               
               if (item.GetType() == typeof(myclass))
               {
                  (myclass)) tempItem = ((myclass)))item;
                  if (tempItem.IsSelected)
                  {
                     // if bound data item still is selected, fix this
                     tempItem.IsSelected = true;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         if (e.RemovedItems != null)
         {
            foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
            {
              
               if (item.GetType() == typeof((myclass))))
               {
                  (myclass)) tempItem = ((myclass)))item;
                  if (tempItem.IsSelected)
                  {
                     // if bound data item still is selected, fix this
                     tempItem.IsSelected = false;
                  }
               }
            }
         }

         e.Handled = true;

         DMItemsList = SelectedItems;
      }

      public ICommand UnselectAllCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<object>((object o) => UnselectAll()); } }

      public IList DMItemsList
      {
         get { return (IList)GetValue(DMItemsListProperty); }
         set { SetValue(DMItemsListProperty, value); }
      }
      private static void OnSelectedItemsListChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
      }
      public static readonly DependencyProperty DMItemsListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DMItemsList", typeof(IList), typeof(DMDataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsListChanged));
    }
```

Comment: Then you need to work with Tab and Shift+Tab, not arrow keys. That will focus next/previous controls in order inside a focus scope.

Comment: I want to navigate items in datagrid where on pressing down/up arrow only focus should move and not selection. Currently when i press down arrow in datgrid selection and focus both moves to next row. I want that only focus should move.

Comment: Then you could catch PreviewKeyDown event on DataGrid and set eventArgs.Handled = True. This will prevent DataGrid to keep processing the event. Then you can add your own behavior(either in same event handler or some other way like Behavior) that will take next row by index, and try to call .Focus() on it.

Comment: yes , i tried the same- public void dgrObjects_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
      {
         DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;
         switch (e.Key)
         {
            case Key.Down:              
              
               dg.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down)); This is not working as its still selecting the next object. Any help in that piece of code will be really appreciated

Comment: I meant you could get the next row item using DataGrid's ItemContainerGenerator and tell it row.Focus().

Comment: Am doing that but problem is selection is also moving along with focus which i dont want

Comment: Can you show the code where you did that?

Comment: public void dgrObjects_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) { DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender; switch (e.Key) { case Key.Down: dg.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));  In previewkey down event am moving focus to down but selection is also getting moved

Comment: That's because you didn't add e.Handled = True in your handler. Try adding that in your preview event handler, otherwise your DataGrid will continue the KeyDown operation handling.